# Not able to see ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

i didn't see any data in listView i get all data from web-service but i didn't see it inside ListView.
I get flow and i understand it never go inside getView() method
Please explain me what's wrong going in that code and suggest me best-one.

```
public class WeatherReport extends Activity {

    ListView listView;
    GPS_Location gpsObj;
    BaseAdapter aAdapter;
    double Latitude, Longitude;
    Bitmap image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.weather_report);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        gpsObj = new GPS_Location(this);
        Latitude = gpsObj.getLatitude();
        Longitude = gpsObj.getLongitude();
        System.out.println("Inside onCreate() ");
        String Url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=" + Latitude + "&lon=" + Longitude + "&cnt=14&mode=json";
        new getJSON().execute(Url);
        //  listView.setAdapter(new BAdapter(this));
    }

    private class getJSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String cityName;
        String Latitude, Longitude;
        ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
        ArrayList<String> humidity;
        ArrayList<String> speed;
        ArrayList<String> weather;
        ArrayList<String> tempMin;
        ArrayList<String> tempMax;
        ArrayList<String> description;
        ArrayList<Bitmap> icon;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String Url = params[0];
            humidity = new ArrayList<String>();
            speed = new ArrayList<String>();
            weather = new ArrayList<String>();
            tempMin = new ArrayList<String>();
            tempMax = new ArrayList<String>();
            icon = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
            description = new ArrayList<String>();
            String data;
            try {
                HttpClient hClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet hGet = new HttpGet(Url);
                ResponseHandler<String> rHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                data = hClient.execute(hGet, rHandler);
                System.out.println("Inside doInBackground  data " + data);
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
                System.out.println("Inside Background jObj " + jObj);
                JSONObject jsonObject = jObj.getJSONObject("city");
                cityName = jsonObject.getString("name");
                JSONObject jObjCoOrd = jsonObject.getJSONObject("coord");
                Latitude = jObjCoOrd.getString("lat");
                System.out.println("Inside Latitude " + Latitude);
                Longitude = jObjCoOrd.getString("lon");
                System.out.println("Inside Longitude " + Longitude);

                JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("list");
                System.out.println("Inside jsonObjList " + jsonArray);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String humidityString = object.getString("humidity");
                    humidity.add(humidityString);
                    String speedString = object.getString("speed");
                    System.out.println("Inside speedString " + speedString);
                    speed.add(speedString);

                    JSONArray weatherArray = object.getJSONArray("weather");
                    JSONObject weatherObj = weatherArray.getJSONObject(0);

                    String iconString = weatherObj.getString("icon");
                    final String iconURL = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + iconString + ".png";
                    image = getImage(iconURL);
                    icon.add(image);
                    System.out.println("Inside icon " + icon);
                    String descriptionString = weatherObj.getString("description");
                    System.out.println("Inside descriptionString " + descriptionString);
                    description.add(descriptionString);

                    JSONObject tempObj = object.getJSONObject("temp");

                    String minTemp = tempObj.getString("min");
                    System.out.println("Inside minTemp " + minTemp);
                    tempMin.add(minTemp);

                    String maxTemp = tempObj.getString("max");
                    System.out.println("Inside maxTemp " + maxTemp);
                    tempMax.add(maxTemp);
                }

                aAdapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(WeatherReport.this,
                        Latitude, Longitude, cityName, humidity, speed, icon, description, tempMin, tempMax);
                listView.setAdapter(aAdapter);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        private Bitmap getImage(String iconURL) {
            InputStream in = null;
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            int responseCode = -1;
            try {

                URL url = new URL(iconURL);//"http://192.xx.xx.xx/mypath/img1.jpg
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.connect();
                responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    //download
                    in = con.getInputStream();
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    in.close();
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("Exception", ex.toString());
            }


            return bmp;
        }

        private class ListViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            Context context;
            public LayoutInflater inflater;
            String Latitude, Longitude, cityName;
            String[] Humidity, Speed, Description1, minTemp, maxTemp ;
            ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap;


            public ListViewCustomAdapter(Context context, String latitude, String longitude, String cityName, ArrayList<String> humidity, ArrayList<String> speed, ArrayList<Bitmap> image, ArrayList<String> description, ArrayList<String> tempMin, ArrayList<String> tempMax) {
                this.context = context;
                this.Latitude = latitude;
                this.Longitude = longitude;
                this.cityName = cityName;
                this.bitmap = icon;
                this.Humidity = humidity.toArray(new String[humidity.size()]);
                this.Speed = speed.toArray(new String[speed.size()]);
                this.Description1 = description.toArray(new String[description.size()]);
                this.minTemp = tempMin.toArray(new String[tempMin.size()]);
                this.maxTemp = tempMax.toArray(new String[tempMax.size()]);
                this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                System.out.println("Inside ListViewCustomAdapter ");
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int i) {
                return i;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int i) {
                return i;
            }

            private class Holder {
                TextView City, MinTemp, MaxTemp, Description, Speed, Latitude, Longitude, Humidity;
                ImageView cloud;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                Holder holder= null;
                View view = convertView;
                System.out.println("Inside getView");
                if(view== null){
                    System.out.println("Inside if getView");
                    holder = new Holder();
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_report_single_item, null);
                    holder.cloud = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cloud);
                    holder.City = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityName);
                    holder.MinTemp= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minTemp);
                    holder.MaxTemp= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.maxTemp);
                    holder.Description=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.weather);
                    holder.Speed =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed);
                    holder.Latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
                    holder.Longitude= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
                    holder.Humidity= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humidity);

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Inside else getView");
                    holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
                    holder.City.setText(cityName);
                    holder.Latitude.setText(Latitude);
                    holder.Longitude.setText(Longitude);
                    holder.MaxTemp.setText(maxTemp[position]);
                    holder.MinTemp.setText(minTemp[position]);
                    holder.Speed.setText(Speed[position]);
                    holder.Description.setText(Description1[position]);
                    holder.cloud.setImageBitmap(bitmap.get(position));
                }

                return convertView;
            }
        }
    }
}

class SingleRow {
    String minTemp, maxTemp, speed, humidity;
    Bitmap img;

    SingleRow(String minTemp, String maxTemp, String speed, String humidity, Bitmap img) {

        this.maxTemp = maxTemp;
        this.minTemp = minTemp;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.humidity = humidity;
        this.img = img;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are setting data in else part in getview method. set them after else.

Comment: @DhavalGondaliya  I do that but still not getting anything...

Comment: Inside minTemp 286.93 Inside maxTemp 300.91 Inside ListViewCustomAdapter These is flow i got inside logcat u can see i never go inside getView()

Comment: You didnt use your custom adapter in your activity. use custom adapter not baseadapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give length of the records which is going to be display .. give array/collection length in get count method

Check the below code for adapter . Added comment also where u made mistakes and suggestions also

Set the listview adapter and all in async task onPostExecute method.

**EDITED**
Check the suggestions i hve marked with with `#### SUGGESTION`

[image]

```
public class WeatherReport extends Activity {

    ListView listView;
    // GPS_Location gpsObj;
    // BaseAdapter aAdapter;
    double Latitude, Longitude;
    Bitmap image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listdata);
        // gpsObj = new GPS_Location(this);
        /*
         * For testing i gve static lat long values as i dnt hve your
         * GPS_Location class
         */
        Latitude = 23;
        Longitude = 73;
        System.out.println("Inside onCreate() ");
        String Url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat="
                + Latitude + "&lon=" + Longitude + "&cnt=14&mode=json";
        new getJSON().execute(Url);
        // listView.setAdapter(new BAdapter(this));
    }

    private class getJSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String cityName;
        String Latitude, Longitude;
        ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
        ArrayList<String> humidity;
        ArrayList<String> speed;
        ArrayList<String> weather;
        ArrayList<String> tempMin;
        ArrayList<String> tempMax;
        ArrayList<String> description;
        ArrayList<String> icon;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            listView.setAdapter(new ListViewCustomAdapter(WeatherReport.this,
                    Latitude, Longitude, cityName, humidity, speed, icon,
                    description, tempMin, tempMax));
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String Url = params[0];
            humidity = new ArrayList<String>();
            speed = new ArrayList<String>();
            weather = new ArrayList<String>();
            tempMin = new ArrayList<String>();
            tempMax = new ArrayList<String>();
            icon = new ArrayList<String>();
            description = new ArrayList<String>();
            String data;
            try {
                HttpClient hClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet hGet = new HttpGet(Url);
                ResponseHandler<String> rHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                data = hClient.execute(hGet, rHandler);
                System.out.println("Inside doInBackground  data " + data);
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
                System.out.println("Inside Background jObj " + jObj);
                JSONObject jsonObject = jObj.getJSONObject("city");
                cityName = jsonObject.getString("name");
                JSONObject jObjCoOrd = jsonObject.getJSONObject("coord");
                Latitude = jObjCoOrd.getString("lat");
                System.out.println("Inside Latitude " + Latitude);
                Longitude = jObjCoOrd.getString("lon");
                System.out.println("Inside Longitude " + Longitude);

                JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("list");
                System.out.println("Inside jsonObjList " + jsonArray);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String humidityString = object.getString("humidity");
                    humidity.add(humidityString);
                    String speedString = object.getString("speed");
                    System.out.println("Inside speedString " + speedString);
                    speed.add(speedString);

                    JSONArray weatherArray = object.getJSONArray("weather");
                    JSONObject weatherObj = weatherArray.getJSONObject(0);

                    String iconString = weatherObj.getString("icon");
                    final String iconURL = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"
                            + iconString + ".png";
                    // #### SUGGESTION

                    // Do not Download images or files like this
                    // to display images use imageloader lazy loading library is
                    // available

                    // https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/tree/master/sample

                    // Comment image downloading related below line and once
                    // check

                    // image = getImage(iconURL);
                    // icon.add(image);

                    // here other change i hve made is converty bitmap array
                    // list to String which will hve images url not bitmap
                    icon.add(iconURL);
                    System.out.println("Inside icon " + icon);
                    String descriptionString = weatherObj
                            .getString("description");
                    System.out.println("Inside descriptionString "
                            + descriptionString);
                    description.add(descriptionString);

                    JSONObject tempObj = object.getJSONObject("temp");

                    String minTemp = tempObj.getString("min");
                    System.out.println("Inside minTemp " + minTemp);
                    tempMin.add(minTemp);

                    String maxTemp = tempObj.getString("max");
                    System.out.println("Inside maxTemp " + maxTemp);
                    tempMax.add(maxTemp);
                }

                // If u do any ui related changes here below exception will come
                // so need to move ui changes in onPostExecute

                // android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:
                // Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can
                // touch its views.

                // listView.setAdapter(new ListViewCustomAdapter(
                // WeatherReport.this, Latitude, Longitude, cityName,
                // humidity, speed, icon, description, tempMin, tempMax));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        private Bitmap getImage(String iconURL) {
            InputStream in = null;
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            int responseCode = -1;
            try {

                URL url = new URL(iconURL);// "http://192.xx.xx.xx/mypath/img1.jpg
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.connect();
                responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    // download
                    in = con.getInputStream();
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    in.close();
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("Exception", ex.toString());
            }

            return bmp;
        }

        private class ListViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            Context context;
            public LayoutInflater inflater;
            String Latitude, Longitude, cityName;
            String[] Humidity, Speed, Description1, minTemp, maxTemp;
            ArrayList<String> bitmap;
            int totalDisplayDatasize = 0;

            public ListViewCustomAdapter(Context context, String latitude,
                    String longitude, String cityName,
                    ArrayList<String> humidity, ArrayList<String> speed,
                    ArrayList<String> image, ArrayList<String> description,
                    ArrayList<String> tempMin, ArrayList<String> tempMax) {
                this.context = context;
                this.Latitude = latitude;
                this.Longitude = longitude;
                this.cityName = cityName;
                this.bitmap = icon;
                this.Humidity = humidity.toArray(new String[humidity.size()]);
                this.Speed = speed.toArray(new String[speed.size()]);
                this.Description1 = description.toArray(new String[description
                        .size()]);
                this.minTemp = tempMin.toArray(new String[tempMin.size()]);
                this.maxTemp = tempMax.toArray(new String[tempMax.size()]);
                // /suggestion : No need to create LayoutInflater instance in
                // constructor
                // this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                // .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                /**
                 * set total data length for count
                 * */
                if (this.Humidity != null)
                    totalDisplayDatasize = this.Humidity.length;
                System.out.println("Inside ListViewCustomAdapter ");
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // this could be one of the reason for not showing listview.set
                // total data length for count
                return totalDisplayDatasize;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int i) {
                return i;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int i) {
                return i;
            }

            private class Holder {
                TextView City, MinTemp, MaxTemp, Description, Speed, Latitude,
                        Longitude, Humidity;
                ImageView cloud;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                Holder holder = null;
                View view = convertView;
                System.out.println("Inside getView");
                if (view == null) {
                    System.out.println("Inside if getView");
                    holder = new Holder();
                    // / No need to create LayoutInflater instance in
                    // constructor

                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(
                            R.layout.list_row_data, null);
                    // Create instance from convertview.findviewbyid instead of
                    // directly using findViewById
                    // holder.cloud = (ImageView) convertView
                    // .findViewById(R.id.cloud);
                    // holder.City = (TextView) convertView
                    // .findViewById(R.id.cityName);
                    holder.MinTemp = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.minTemp);
                    holder.MaxTemp = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.maxTemp);
                    holder.Description = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.weather);
                    holder.Speed = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.speed);
                    holder.Latitude = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.latitude);
                    holder.Longitude = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.longitude);

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Inside else getView");
                    holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();

                }// set values here for each row

                // holder.City.setText(cityName);
                holder.Latitude.setText("Lat : " + Latitude);
                holder.Longitude.setText("Long : " + Longitude);
                holder.MaxTemp.setText("maxTemp : " + maxTemp[position]);
                holder.MinTemp.setText("minTemp : " + minTemp[position]);
                holder.Speed.setText("Speed : " + Speed[position]);
                holder.Description.setText("Description : "
                        + Description1[position]);
                // #### SUGGESTION

                // TO display image use ImageLoader which will download image in
                // background and will display
                // https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/tree/master/sample

                // holder.cloud.setImageBitmap(bitmap.get(position));
                return convertView;
            }
        }
    }
}

class SingleRow {
    String minTemp, maxTemp, speed, humidity;
    Bitmap img;

    SingleRow(String minTemp, String maxTemp, String speed, String humidity,
            Bitmap img) {

        this.maxTemp = maxTemp;
        this.minTemp = minTemp;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.humidity = humidity;
        this.img = img;
    }

}
```

list_row_data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/speed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffff8800" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weather"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffff8800" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latitude"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffff8800" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/longitude"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffff8800" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/minTemp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffff8800" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/maxTemp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffff8800" />

</LinearLayout>
```

listview_.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listdata"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey @user1140237 i Still not getting anything by ur code, it never enter in getView().

Comment: @ULHASPATIL can u pls post your xml layout once ?

Comment: i post it on gist please follow the link and check layout.

https://gist.github.com/18ulhaspatil/edc6a0c3d8a898c5a88e

Comment: @ULHASPATIL hve u check the suggestion and code which i hve post ...?

Comment: Thank you @user1140237
It works but i also want images for each weather report and i don't know how imageLibrary use. 
Why it is not possible to download image runtime and show it.

Comment: @ULHASPATIL its is possible but not proper way.

Comment: Hey @user1140237 sorry to bother u again...
But i have no experience in CustomListView or use image library. so can u send me any example link to better understand how image library use and show image in these kind of situation.

Comment: @ULHASPATIL now this thing is something like out of the question ... here your question is regarding not displaying listview and its showing now.. so for image lazy loading you can post seperate question where ppl can share more about tht particular thing... and if regarding listview not displaying if its resolve thn mark as ans and gve upvote if & only if its showing.. and for image loading related i hve already mentioned link in code

Comment: @ULHASPATIL sorry bt it will required more change in ans ... but if you wants to know about Image loading libraries related you can check https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
http://square.github.io/picasso/
https://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: Thank you @user1140237
I will check it out and learn it. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED

First
write

```
      @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Humidity.length();;
        }
```

instead of

```
       @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }
```

And you are setting value to row view in getview()'s else section set values after if else

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Holder holder= null;
            View view = convertView;
            System.out.println("Inside getView");
            if(view== null){
                System.out.println("Inside if getView");
                holder = new Holder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_report_single_item, null);
                holder.cloud = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cloud);
               convertView.setTag(holder);

            }else{
                System.out.println("Inside else getView");
                holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();

            }

                holder.City.setText(cityName);
                holder.Latitude.setText(Latitude);
                holder.Longitude.setText(Longitude);
                holder.MaxTemp.setText(maxTemp[position]);
                holder.MinTemp.setText(minTemp[position]);
                holder.Speed.setText(Speed[position]);
                holder.Description.setText(Description1[position]);
                holder.cloud.setImageBitmap(bitmap.get(position));

            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: @prachi u forgot to set holder in converview set tag

Comment: Inside minTemp 286.93

Inside maxTemp 300.91

Inside ListViewCustomAdapter


These is flow i got inside logcat u can see i never go inside getView() ....

Answer (score 0):

Hi your  getCount() in the base adaptor returns 0 change it to you total size of data you have like this

```
 @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Humidity.length;
        }
```

and also change

```
  aAdapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(WeatherReport.this,
                    Latitude, Longitude, cityName, humidity, speed, icon, description, tempMin, tempMax);
            listView.setAdapter(aAdapter);
```

from the **doInBackground** to **onPostExecute** methord in the Async Task Class

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
aAdapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(WeatherReport.this,
                    Latitude, Longitude, cityName, humidity, speed, icon, description, tempMin, tempMax);
            listView.setAdapter(aAdapter);
    }
```

The complete Code Look Like This

```
public class WeatherReport extends Activity {

ListView listView;
GPS_Location gpsObj;
BaseAdapter aAdapter;
double Latitude, Longitude;
Bitmap image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.weather_report);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    gpsObj = new GPS_Location(this);
    Latitude = gpsObj.getLatitude();
    Longitude = gpsObj.getLongitude();
    System.out.println("Inside onCreate() ");
    String Url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=" + Latitude + "&lon=" + Longitude + "&cnt=14&mode=json";
    new getJSON().execute(Url);
    //  listView.setAdapter(new BAdapter(this));
}

private class getJSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String cityName;
    String Latitude, Longitude;
    ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
    ArrayList<String> humidity;
    ArrayList<String> speed;
    ArrayList<String> weather;
    ArrayList<String> tempMin;
    ArrayList<String> tempMax;
    ArrayList<String> description;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> icon;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String Url = params[0];
        humidity = new ArrayList<String>();
        speed = new ArrayList<String>();
        weather = new ArrayList<String>();
        tempMin = new ArrayList<String>();
        tempMax = new ArrayList<String>();
        icon = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        description = new ArrayList<String>();
        String data;
        try {
            HttpClient hClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet hGet = new HttpGet(Url);
            ResponseHandler<String> rHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            data = hClient.execute(hGet, rHandler);
            System.out.println("Inside doInBackground  data " + data);
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
            System.out.println("Inside Background jObj " + jObj);
            JSONObject jsonObject = jObj.getJSONObject("city");
            cityName = jsonObject.getString("name");
            JSONObject jObjCoOrd = jsonObject.getJSONObject("coord");
            Latitude = jObjCoOrd.getString("lat");
            System.out.println("Inside Latitude " + Latitude);
            Longitude = jObjCoOrd.getString("lon");
            System.out.println("Inside Longitude " + Longitude);

            JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("list");
            System.out.println("Inside jsonObjList " + jsonArray);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String humidityString = object.getString("humidity");
                humidity.add(humidityString);
                String speedString = object.getString("speed");
                System.out.println("Inside speedString " + speedString);
                speed.add(speedString);

                JSONArray weatherArray = object.getJSONArray("weather");
                JSONObject weatherObj = weatherArray.getJSONObject(0);

                String iconString = weatherObj.getString("icon");
                final String iconURL = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + iconString + ".png";
                image = getImage(iconURL);
                icon.add(image);
                System.out.println("Inside icon " + icon);
                String descriptionString = weatherObj.getString("description");
                System.out.println("Inside descriptionString " + descriptionString);
                description.add(descriptionString);

                JSONObject tempObj = object.getJSONObject("temp");

                String minTemp = tempObj.getString("min");
                System.out.println("Inside minTemp " + minTemp);
                tempMin.add(minTemp);

                String maxTemp = tempObj.getString("max");
                System.out.println("Inside maxTemp " + maxTemp);
                tempMax.add(maxTemp);
            }

           //Removed Setting Adaptor from do in background to onPostExecute

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        //The Last Step in Async Task Do set adaptor here

        aAdapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(WeatherReport.this,
                Latitude, Longitude, cityName, humidity, speed, icon, description, tempMin, tempMax);
        listView.setAdapter(aAdapter);
    }
}

    private Bitmap getImage(String iconURL) {
        InputStream in = null;
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        int responseCode = -1;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(iconURL);//"http://192.xx.xx.xx/mypath/img1.jpg
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.connect();
            responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                //download
                in = con.getInputStream();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                in.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Exception", ex.toString());
        }


        return bmp;
    }

    private class ListViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Context context;
        public LayoutInflater inflater;
        String Latitude, Longitude, cityName;
        String[] Humidity, Speed, Description1, minTemp, maxTemp ;
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap;


        public ListViewCustomAdapter(Context context, String latitude, String longitude, String cityName, ArrayList<String> humidity, ArrayList<String> speed, ArrayList<Bitmap> image, ArrayList<String> description, ArrayList<String> tempMin, ArrayList<String> tempMax) {
            this.context = context;
            this.Latitude = latitude;
            this.Longitude = longitude;
            this.cityName = cityName;
            this.bitmap = icon;
            this.Humidity = humidity.toArray(new String[humidity.size()]);
            this.Speed = speed.toArray(new String[speed.size()]);
            this.Description1 = description.toArray(new String[description.size()]);
            this.minTemp = tempMin.toArray(new String[tempMin.size()]);
            this.maxTemp = tempMax.toArray(new String[tempMax.size()]);
            this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            System.out.println("Inside ListViewCustomAdapter ");
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            //Prev you have been returning 0 its changed from 0 to Humidity.length so that base adaptor show the result as listview

            return Humidity.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        private class Holder {
            TextView City, MinTemp, MaxTemp, Description, Speed, Latitude, Longitude, Humidity;
            ImageView cloud;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Holder holder= null;
            View view = convertView;
            System.out.println("Inside getView");
            if(view== null){
                System.out.println("Inside if getView");
                holder = new Holder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_report_single_item, null);
                holder.cloud = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cloud);
                holder.City = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityName);
                holder.MinTemp= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minTemp);
                holder.MaxTemp= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.maxTemp);
                holder.Description=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.weather);
                holder.Speed =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed);
                holder.Latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
                holder.Longitude= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
                holder.Humidity= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humidity);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Inside else getView");
                holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
                holder.City.setText(cityName);
                holder.Latitude.setText(Latitude);
                holder.Longitude.setText(Longitude);
                holder.MaxTemp.setText(maxTemp[position]);
                holder.MinTemp.setText(minTemp[position]);
                holder.Speed.setText(Speed[position]);
                holder.Description.setText(Description1[position]);
                holder.cloud.setImageBitmap(bitmap.get(position));
            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }



class SingleRow {
    String minTemp, maxTemp, speed, humidity;
    Bitmap img;

    SingleRow(String minTemp, String maxTemp, String speed, String humidity, Bitmap img) {

        this.maxTemp = maxTemp;
        this.minTemp = minTemp;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.humidity = humidity;
        this.img = img;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create and set `adapter` of your `ListView` in [`onPostExecute`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) method of `getJSON` class.

[`getCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getCount()) - How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter. You are returning `0` means you are setting the adapter's data as `0` so no row will be inflated.

In adapter change all those String array to `ArrayList<String>` besides that you need to change the constructor, `getCount` and `getView` portion

Declaration

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap, Humidity, Speed, Description1, minTemp, maxTemp;
```

constructor

```
public ListViewCustomAdapter(Context context, String latitude, String longitude, String cityName, ArrayList<String> humidity, ArrayList<String> speed, ArrayList<Bitmap> image, ArrayList<String> description, ArrayList<String> tempMin, ArrayList<String> tempMax) {
    this.context = context;
    this.Latitude = latitude;
    this.Longitude = longitude;
    this.cityName = cityName;
    this.bitmap = icon;
    this.Humidity = humidity;
    this.Speed = speed;
    this.Description1 = description;
    this.minTemp = tempMin;
    this.maxTemp = tempMax;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    System.out.println("Inside ListViewCustomAdapter ");
}
```

getCount portion

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
   return humidity.size();
}
```

getView portion

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   Holder holder= null;
   View view = convertView;
   System.out.println("Inside getView");
   if(view== null){
        System.out.println("Inside if getView");
        holder = new Holder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_report_single_item, parent, false);
        holder.cloud = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cloud);
        holder.City = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityName);
        holder.MinTemp= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minTemp);
        holder.MaxTemp= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.maxTemp);
        holder.Description=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.weather);
        holder.Speed =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed);
        holder.Latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
        holder.Longitude= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
        holder.Humidity= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humidity);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
   }else{
      System.out.println("Inside else getView");
      holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
   }
   holder.City.setText(cityName);
   holder.Latitude.setText(Latitude);
   holder.Longitude.setText(Longitude);
   holder.MaxTemp.setText(maxTemp.get(position));
   holder.MinTemp.setText(minTemp.get(position));
   holder.Speed.setText(Speed.get(position));
   holder.Description.setText(Description1.get(position));
   holder.cloud.setImageBitmap(bitmap.get(position));
   return convertView;
 }
```