# Android Studio itemsAdapter and custom ListView not working

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-listview

I am in Android Studio trying to implement a custom ListView.  I have created an xml file called "custom_layout_rachel.xml" and have put it in my "layout" folder.  This file contains the code for how I want my ListView to look.

I am trying to make the list view in my page called "activity_urgent__important.xml" to look like the one in "custom_layout_rachel.xml".  In this file, I have the following code:

```
<ListView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:id="@+id/lvItems"
      tools:listitem="@layout/custom_layout_rachel"
 />
```

In Android Studio, the custom layout is showing up, but when I run the app on my emulator, it is not there.

The java code for this activity, looks like:

```
lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
items = new ArrayList<String>();
itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.custom_layout_rachel, items);
lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

on the third line is where my error is.

Does anyone know why I can't do this or why I am getting an error?

Thank you!!!

New:

```
       lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    readItems();
    itemsAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, items);
    lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

Getting an error on "Custom List Adapter(this, items)

I do not have adapter code, but I did start the following, I could implement it if it would work:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private int id;
    private List<String> items ;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId , List<String> list )
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        mContext = context;
        id = textViewResourceId;
        items = list ;
    }

public CustomListAdapter(Context context , List<String> list) {
    super(context, items);
}

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View mView = v ;
        if(mView == null){
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mView = vi.inflate(id, null);
        }

        TextView text = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        if(items.get(position) != null )
        {
            text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            text.setText(items.get(position));
            text.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            int color = Color.argb( 200, 255, 64, 64 );
            text.setBackgroundColor( color );

        }

        return mView;
    }
```

Comment: what error are we talking about ?

Comment: change the id of the textview insside custom_layout_rachel to     android:id="@android:id/text1"

Comment: @rachel if you wants to use custom listview with BaseAdapter please check code snippet in these answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/28104066/1140237  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28038963/1140237  only for listview & BaseAdapter

Answer (score 1):

In your second `CustomListAdapter` constructor, initialize `mContext` and items since `mContext` will be used in inflating the view in `getView()` method.

```
public CustomListAdapter(Context context , List<String> list) {
    super(context, items);
     mContext = context;
     items = list ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    If you are creating your own adpater extending String type. You don't have to pass android.R.layout.custom_layout_rachel in your third line of code. 
    You will be inflating your custom_layout for listview inside getView method ,within adapter. 

    Simply pass the context and values needed to be populated in Listview. 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,items);
    Change your adapter constructor to the same. 

    if it doesn't work please post the adapter code. 

    Update your code like this.

    public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private Context mContext;
        private int id;
        private List<String> items ;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public CustomListAdapter(Context context,List<String> list )
        {   super(context,list);
            this.mContext = context;
            this.items = list ;
             this.inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context)
        } 
     public int getCount()
    {
    items.length;
    (or)
    items.size();
    }
    @Override 
        public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
        { 
            if(v== null){
                  v = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout_rachel, null);
            } 

            TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            if(items.get(position) != null )
            { 
                text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                text.setText(items.get(position));
                text.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                int color = Color.argb( 200, 255, 64, 64 );
                text.setBackgroundColor( color );

            } 

            return v;
        } 

changes in your code 

  lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    readItems(); 
    itemsAdapter = new CustomListAdapter<String>(this, items);
    lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

Comment: I think it will work, one last problem: the line in the customListAdapter file that reads " super(context, list);", the "list" is giving me an error saying that it is not initialized.

Comment: Inside getcount() method add this.items.size() instead of items.size().

Comment: Add an integer value to super. Super(context,list,0);